# Как сделать, чтобы блок не заходил за границы?

Tags: javascript, html

сейчас вылазит со всех 4 сторон

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.item');
el.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);


function mousedown(e) {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
  let prevX = e.clientX;
  let prevY = e.clientY;

  function mousemove(e) {
    let newX = prevX - e.clientX;
    let newY = prevY - e.clientY;
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    el.style.left = rect.left - newX + 'px';
    el.style.top = rect.top - newY + 'px';
    prevX = e.clientX;
    prevY = e.clientY;
  }

  function mouseup() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
  }
}
```

```css
.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
<p>Lorem i</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Не хотите это сделать на canvas-е ?)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Границы в drag\`n\`drop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1407302/%d0%93%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-dragndrop)

Comment: Какой блок, где вылазит, какой класс?